# Decrement score in Redis or remove if 0

Tags: redis

How can I decrement score of one Redis element by 1 in sorted set or remove it if it's value is 0? Currently I am using `$redis.zincrby user_cart, -1, params[:product_id]` (Rails 4.1.4), but I get negative values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ZINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby)'s reply is the new score so you can check it and issue a [ZREM](http://redis.io/commands/zrem) if it is < 1.

Answer (score 7):

You can write a LUA script that does it on the Redis server side.
You can use this one:

```
local ans = redis.call('ZINCRBY', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
if   tonumber(ans) < 1 then
    redis.call('ZREM', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]) 
end
return (tonumber(ans) < 1 and '-1' or ans)
```

On any deletion it will return `-1` otherwise it will return the new member score.

Here's a sinnpet from a test run:

```
evalsha 6e8a61a2367772383f535587ce75e92d4e047fcf 1 myzset 3 blah
"3"
zrank myzset blah
(integer) 0
evalsha 6e8a61a2367772383f535587ce75e92d4e047fcf 1 myzset -3 blah
"-1"
zrank myzset blah
(nil)
evalsha 6e8a61a2367772383f535587ce75e92d4e047fcf 1 myzset -3 blah
"-1"
zrank myzset blah
(nil)
```

Comment: Nice. Why not return '0' instead of '-1' when the element was removed?

Comment: @EduardoParejaTobes No reason. 0 is also a good answer as well. But it will be harder to change the logic to allow 0 and only delete negatives later on.

Comment: This answer makes more sense than the accepted answer in case you're using pipelining on client side and want a specific behaviour like this one.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about sorted sets, but this problem also comes up with INCR/DECR keys. Here's an example using Lua script with PHP Predis:

```php
$lua = <<<LUA
    local c = redis.call('DECR', KEYS[1])
    if c == 0 then 
        redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1]) 
    end
    return c
LUA;

// Argument 1 is the Lua script.
// Argument 2 is the number of keys being passed to the script (always 1 for this script).
// Argument 3 is the key to decrement/delete.
$count = $predisClient->eval($lua, 1, 'foo-bar-key');
```

An alternative would be to use a WATCH + MULTI + EXEC transaction, but the Redis community seems to prefer Lua.