# How reset key increment in Redis after DECR?

Tags: redis, node-redis

How reset key increment in Redis to zero? In documentation did not find command

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decrement score in Redis or remove if 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693355/decrement-score-in-redis-or-remove-if-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either delete it or simply `SET` it to zero.